# Lottery probability -> Does winning affect others?

Tags: probability, statistics

I came up with this question today since in italy somebody has won the national lottery:

(I know nothing about statistics)

there is a town with 10 spots where you can play lottery, and 1000 people play on each spot.
One of these guys wins. The probability that the same person could possibly win again in the future, i immagine to be veeeeeery small. So the probability that the same guy wins two times in his life would be (at least to my understanding) very remote.

But if I take this statement and expand it, I could say the same thing for the lottery spot he playd in. Iv'e never heared of any shop in history where they cracked the jackpot twice. So my question is: does his winning in any way statistically affect the other 999 people playing in that shop? if so, what about the entire city?

my logical thinking would tell me that If i have my numbers it doesn't make any difference where I play, since the numbers dont change whether I play them in one spot or another... At the other hand, it is very unlikely to have a winner in the same spot twice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very unlikely that any given person wins twice. But given that he has already won once, he is as likely to win a second time than everybody else is to win for the first time.
Same for spots and similar. Thus, winning once does not affect the probability to win a second time, or everybody else's probability to win for the first time.

So why don't you hear more about people winning twice? Think of people as red and blue balls: they are red if they didn't won there lottery, yet, and blue otherwise. Now you draw by random a ball with equal probability (decide on the winner of the next lottery). Even though this means that every single ball has the same chance to be drawn, the color of the ball will most likely be red (=first time winner), since most people didn't yet win the lottery and thus most balls are red. Thus, as long as most people didn't win the lottery, the next winner will most likely be a first time winner, simply because there are way more potential first time winners than potential two time winners.

Comment: thank you very much very clear!

Answer (score 1):

Two different games of lottery are what in statistics we call "independent events". That means winning it one time does not affect in any way to the second game of lottery, and his isolated probability of winning again is equal to any other person.

Despite this, the answer is different if you think about "The probability of winning the lottery two times", that would be (assuming there are only 2 games of lottery and both have the same chance of winning $p$) a probability of $p^2$.

PS: I think you're falling into the [Gambler's Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy). Check that link for more information about it.

Comment: thank you very much... checking it out..